# JSON error request is not defined

Tags: javascript, xml, json

When I do console.log(req.responsetext) i get [11:38:04.967] ReferenceError: req is not defined. But i define req as a new xml request on window load so I am kind of stumped. Is there a way that I should be passing a reference?

the console output is as follows

```
[12:29:06.839] GET getterms.php?query=DFA [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 99ms]
[12:29:06.888] SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character @ search.php:21
[12:33:24.316] console.log(req.responsetext)
[12:33:24.318] ReferenceError: req is not defined
```

Any and all help would be most gratefully appreciated. Thank you to anyone who takes the time to read and/or answer even if you cannot help!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Auto Complete</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();     //the HTTP request which will invoke the query
            var input = document.getElementById('search');      //where to grab the search from
            var output = document.getElementById('results');    //where to display the sugestions

            input.oninput = getSuggestions;

            function getSuggestions() {
                req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    output.innerHTML = "";  //CLEAR the previous results!! only once the server can process new ones though
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && input.value != "") {
                        var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
                            addSuggestion(response[i].terms);
                    }
                }               
                req.open('GET', 'getterms.php?query=' + input.value, true); //GET request to getterms.php?=
                req.send(null);
            }

            addSuggestion = function (suggestion) {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                var p = document.createElement('p');
                div.classList.add('suggestion');        //suggestion[x]...
                p.textContent = suggestion;             
                div.appendChild(p);
                output.appendChild(div);

                div.onclick = function() {
                    input.value = p.innerHTML;  //set the search box
                    getSuggestions();           //GET new suggesions
                }


            }
        }
    </script>

    <input type='text' id='search' name='search' autofocus='autofocus'>
    <div id='results'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

edit this is my php page that echos the json.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

if (!isset($_GET['query']) || empty($_GET['query']))
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
else {


    $db = new PDO(
    my database
    );


    $search_query = $db->prepare("
        SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `word` LIKE :keywords LIMIT 5
    ");

    $params = array(
        ':keywords' => $_GET['query'] . '%',
    );

    $search_query->execute($params);
    $results = $search_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($results);
}
?>
```

Comment: Where are you actually calling `console.log(req.responseText)`?

Comment: in my console when i debug with firebug

Comment: Why do you expect `req` to be defined? You define it **inside** of `window.onload`, so that's the scope that it's defined. It's not defined in the global scope (where the console executes)

Comment: I am running current verison of firefox. Should i put console.log in the file and see what it says?

Comment: If you `console.log` something where it's defined, then yes, it should output something. The `window.onload` scope isn't the same as the global scope.

Comment: You probably want to move `var req = new XMLHttpRequest();` **into** `getSuggestions`

Comment: So I moved the var req inside and it still is not working. I am pretty sure my json encoding is right, so the only thing I think it can be is that html request

Comment: Chris have you tried removing var?

Comment: Because if you move it inside you still have a scope prob

Comment: @PeterBartels If you remove `var`, you'll only ever be able to send 1 AJAX request (which is what's currently happening anyways). That's not what they want at all. Every time `getSuggestions` is called, it needs to make a new request (meaning, it needs to make a **new** `XMLHttpRequest`).

Comment: When I removed the var and put it back in the window on load i still get [12:57:46.146] SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character @ search.php:22... This is line 22 for reference   var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);

Comment: Nope that's why he uses req.open you'll only need to instantiate it once

Comment: Which character is on line 22. It's a php problem too!

Comment: this is line 22 for reference var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);

Comment: What's that trailing comma doing there in the array?

Comment: @PeterBartels That doesn't matter. If things happen fast enough, things get overwritten, which is not desired. You need to create a new `XMLHttpRequest` for every request.

Comment: Oh wow, trailing comma! Well it's not throwing the error anymore but still not popping up in my div grrrrrrrr

Comment: It is adding the divs for the suggestions but the content in them is null.

Comment: How would I debug to see what response[i].terms contains?

Comment: Nevermind I am an idiot. I forgot I changed my database from terms to word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope problem! Remove var in front of req to make it global and it should work

Comment: This wasn't the answer but you did help me find it so I am definitely grateful!